# Check if strings are equals and ternary operator in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In my playbook, I have this:

```
#More things
- include: deploy_new.yml
  vars:
    service_type: "{{ expose_service == 'true' | ternary('NodePort', 'ClusterIP') }}"
    when: service_up|failed
```

When `expose_service` is true, I want `service_type` to be set to *NodePort*, and *ClusterIP* otherwise.

However, `service_type` is set to `False` in all cases.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Solved!

```
service_type: "{{ 'NodePort' if expose_service == 'true' else 'ClusterIP' }}"
```

Comment: In my opinion this answer does not answer the question that were asking about ternary. This is more a workaround

Answer (score 45):

In your example you are applying the ternary filter to the `'true'` string. Effectively you are comparing the value of `expose_service` with the string  `'NodePort'` and always get `false` in result.

You need to enclose the equality operator-clause in parentheses:

```
 - include: deploy_new.yml
   vars:
     service_type: "{{ (expose_service == true) | ternary('NodePort', 'ClusterIP') }}"
   when: service_up|failed
```

---

The other other two points addressed in this answer:

- you use the string `'true'` instead of Boolean
- `when` directive is on wrong indentation level (you effectively pass the variable called `when`)

Answer (score 4):

I'll elaborate first point in [techraf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41819670/12396197)'s answer. Two other points (`when` identation and `'true'` as string instead of boolean `true`) still stand too.

So, the question was "What am I doing wrong?". Answer is: operator precedence.

In `{{ expose_service == 'true' | ternary('NodePort', 'ClusterIP') }}`, filter is applied to 'true' first. So, Ansible evaluates:

- `{{ expose_service == ('true' | ternary('NodePort', 'ClusterIP')) }}`
- `'true' | ternary('NodePort', 'ClusterIP') = 'NodePort'` because quoted non-empty string is still boolean non-false.

  → `{{ expose_service == 'NodePort' }}`

  which is apparently false.