# How to make ansible interpolate the variables or facts in the return section of the ternary filter?

Tags: variables, ansible, return, resolution, ternary

How to make use of variables or  facts in the return section of ternary filter?
eg: set_facts:
var1="{{ (true) | ternary('ansible_os_family','ansible_os_family'|upper) }}"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if strings are equals and ternary operator in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160668/check-if-strings-are-equals-and-ternary-operator-in-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

kindly discard this. Return section seem to consider any variales when passw